# New UI for Stack Overflow Mobile?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface, mobile-web

The new user interface has been rolled out on Stack Overflow, and a previous post asking about the other Stack Exchange sites on which the theme will be rolled out was also answered.

So my question is, when will this new Stack Overflow user interface be added to the **mobile** version of Stack Overflow? Because when I open Stack Overflow in my browser on my Android phone, I still get the old user interface on the mobile version of the site on my phone.

Just for clarification, I am not asking about the Stack Exchange app; I am asking about opening the mobile site of Stack Overflow on my browser on my Android phone.

Comment: What new theme? I don't see different colors, background, fonts, etc. Maybe you installed something.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Didn't they change the header bar and "floatiness" and things? I don't use SO frequently, but I think the inbox and stuff moved to the upper right-hand corner, rather than the upper left-hand corner, where it still is on EL&U and other sites? Having said that, I don't use an Android, but I'd never consider using the mobile site over the SE app on iOS. Way too painful.

Comment: The StackOverflow theme was updated a while ago. If you open the desktop site, or full site, then you see that the header is now white, and that the user interface has changed now

Comment: That is only the top bar, not the whole "theme". Please clarify that you mean the new top bar.

Comment: But that is not the case for the mobile site. So, when will bring this new UI to the mobile site?

Comment: Dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343239/are-there-any-plans-for-the-mobile-version-of-the-website-to-incorporate-the-new

Comment: Sorry for the vocab confusion, just fixed my post. I was asking about the new user interface of stackoverflow.

Comment: And I was not referring to the top bar only, just to clarify.

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer so to what else exactly? They did not change other things. We still vote the same, post the same, etc

Comment: @ShadowWizard Any other minor UI tweak that may have taken place other than the top bar revamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dan Bron commented:

> Didn't they change the header bar and "floatiness" and things?

Yes, that top bar change is still in the testing phase now. I don't think this is the right time to ask to update the layout, *if* there is something to change at all.

Indeed, they may update some colors, but the fancy stuff isn't really useful on mobile at all, so I hope they leave those things out. As an example: a search bar between the site name and notifications for example isn't really doable on mobile.

Comment: So have they got anything else in mind for the mobile version of the site?

Comment: Not as far as I know. The last update was the user profile page update and that was a while ago.